# South Lake Tahoe travel by Public transport

Tags: california

I  am planning to travel to South Lake Tahoe in Mid-March. I am a tourist and do not have my car over there. How can I travel within South Lake Tahoe for sight seeing please? Is there any public transportation available which takes to places nearby sightseeing places?

Comment: The city website has a [page](https://www.cityofslt.us/657/Alternative-Transportation) that lists transportation options. There's probably also Uber/Lyft, and if you're staying at one of the resorts, they can probably arrange a private car.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that looks like enough to base an answer on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BlueGo](http://tahoetransportation.org/transit/south-shore-services) is the bus service in South Lake Tahoe. [This page](http://tahoetransportation.org/transit/tahoe-transportation-map-1) has an overview of the various bus services around Lake Tahoe.